# Spotfire Export data table using TERR function

Tags: spotfire, terr

I need to export (to a folder) a few tables I have created within spotfire. The idea is to do it using a TERR function. I would like to export as stdf or sbdf format.

The only example I have found is How to import:

http://www.cambridgesoft.com/support/EnterpriseSupport/KnowledgeBase/FAQ/details/Default.aspx?TechNote=2883

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried the following, but didn't work:                                                                            mytable <- table1
exportDataToSBDF(mytable, file="C:\User\Desktop\File\test")

Comment: I found the solution:  mytable <- table1 exportDataToSBDF(mytable, file="C:/User/Desktop/File/test.sbdf") and it did work.

Comment: @thundermils- Could you please post your complete solution?